# How to manipulate a string and variable inside same loop

Tags: batch-file

1 Need help to shorten the code

2.(If posible) about case sensitive  when mapping

Sample.Bat:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Data=HELLO"


:Encrypt/Decrypt_Rot13

set Encrypted_Data=!Data!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:A=A#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:B=B#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:C=C#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:D=D#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:E=E#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:F=F#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:G=G#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:H=H#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:I=I#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:J=J#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:K=K#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:L=L#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:M=M#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:N=N#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:O=O#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:P=P#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:Q=Q#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:R=R#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:S=S#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:T=T#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:U=U#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:V=V#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:W=W#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:X=X#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:Y=Y#!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:Z=Z#!

set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:A#=N!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:B#=O!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:C#=P!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:D#=Q!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:E#=R!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:F#=S!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:G#=T!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:H#=U!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:I#=V!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:J#=W!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:K#=X!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:L#=Y!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:M#=Z!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:N#=A!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:O#=B!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:P#=C!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:Q#=D!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:R#=E!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:S#=F!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:T#=G!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:U#=H!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:V#=I!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:W#=J!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:X#=K!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:Y#=L!
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:Z#=M!

echo. 
echo. Original Data:%data% 
echo. 
echo. Encrypted/Decrypted Data:%Encrypted_Data%
echo. 
pause
```

As you can see, i use mapping method and It worked perfectly (Input=HELLO,Output=URYYB),But i realy it tiring to modify it one by one if Needed or to make it as micro.

But when i trying to Shorten the code by using Loop and using same method .

Sample.Bat:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Data=HELLO"

set "Process=Rot13"

set "Rot13_input= ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
set "Rot13_output= NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM"

::set "xxxxxx_input= xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
::set "xxxxxx_output= xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

if %Process% equ Rot13 set "Maxdigit=27"

for /l %%n in (1,1,%Maxdigit%) do ^
set "%Process%_input_%%n=!Rot13_input:~%%n,1!" & ^
set "%Process%_output_%%n=!Rot13_output:~%%n,1!"

::set Rot13_input_
::set Rot13_output_

set Encrypted_Data=!Data!

:: STUCK BELOW ::

for /l %%n in (1,1,%Maxdigit%) do ^
set Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data:%Rot13_input_%%n%=%Rot13_input_%%n%#!

echo %Encrypted_Data%

:: STUCK ABOVE ::

pause

echo. 
echo. Original Data:%data% 
echo. 
echo. Encrypted/Decrypted Data:%Encrypted_Data%
echo. 
pause
```

I am stuck(error output) at second LOOP,Can anyone fix this or Maybe another methods it can be done?

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel: [ROT13 obfuscator](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rot-13#Batch_File)

Comment: Thanks,Rot13 just a sample to my question , but i trying to see the code from your link

Comment: Try this: `for /l %%n in (1,1,%Maxdigit%) do call set "Encrypted_Data=%%Encrypted_Data:!Rot13_input_%%n!=!Rot13_input_%%n!#%%"` (this establishes 3 layers of variable expansion: 1. index `%%n`, 2. search and replace strings, 3. whole string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem ---------------

set "Process=Rot13"

set "Rot13_input= ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
set "Rot13_output= NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM"

if %Process% equ Rot13 set "Maxdigit=26"

for /L %%n in (1,1,%Maxdigit%) do for /F %%c in ("!%Process%_input:~%%n,1!") do (
   set "%Process%_input_%%c=%%n"
)

rem ---------------

set "Data=HELLO"

set "DataLen=0"
for /L %%a in (10,-1,0) do (
   set /A "newLen=DataLen+(1<<%%a)"
   for %%b in (!newLen!) do if "!Data:~%%b,1!" neq "" set "DataLen=%%b"
)

set "Encrypted_Data="
for /L %%i in (0,1,%DataLen%) do for /F %%c in ("!Data:~%%i,1!") do for /F %%j in ("!%Process%_input_%%c!") do (
   set "Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data!!Rot13_output:~%%j,1!"
)


echo Original Data: %data% 
echo/ 
echo Encrypted/Decrypted Data: %Encrypted_Data%
echo/ 
pause
```

And this is the case sensitive version:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem ---------------

set "Process=Rot13"

set "Rot13_input= ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
set "Rot13_output= NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm"

if %Process% equ Rot13 set "Maxdigit=26"

for /L %%n in (0,1,%Maxdigit%) do for /F "delims=" %%c in ("!%Process%_input:~%%n,1!") do (
   set "%Process%_input_%%c=%%n"
)

rem ---------------

set "Data=Hello World"

set "DataLen=0"
for /L %%a in (10,-1,0) do (
   set /A "newLen=DataLen+(1<<%%a)"
   for %%b in (!newLen!) do if "!Data:~%%b,1!" neq "" set "DataLen=%%b"
)

set "Encrypted_Data="
for /L %%i in (0,1,%DataLen%) do for /F "delims=" %%c in ("!Data:~%%i,1!") do (
   set "index=!%Process%_input_%%c!"
   if "!Rot13_input:%%c=%%c!" neq "%Rot13_input%" set /A "index+=Maxdigit"
   for /F %%j in ("!index!") do set "Encrypted_Data=!Encrypted_Data!!Rot13_output:~%%j,1!"
)


echo Original Data: %data% 
echo/ 
echo Encrypted/Decrypted Data: %Encrypted_Data%
echo/ 
pause
```

Comment: Can anyone  share the link or explain about using shift(1<<%%a),because i don't understand  it completely ..